# How to dynamically replace methods with Byte Buddy?

Tags: java, assembly, byte, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

I'm trying to replace methods in a class with their counterparts in a subpackage, if they exist. For example, if I have a class "name.package.ClassName" and I want to replace its methods with those in "name.package.subpackage.ClassName".

I'm using Byte Buddy and this technique:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
    .type(ElementMatchers.any())
    .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classloader, JavaModule javaModule, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain) {
            String className = typeDescription.getSimpleName();
            String packageName = typeDescription.getPackage().getName();
            String subPackageName = packageName + ".subpackage";
            try {
                System.err.println("Sub class FOUND for " + className + " in package: " +subPackageName);
                Class<?> subClass = Class.forName(subPackageName+ "." + className);
                return builder
                    .method(ElementMatchers.named("methodName_isWorking")) 
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(subClass));                                    
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("Sub class not found for " + className);
            }
        }
    }).installOn(instrumentation);;
```

The problem is that if I use the method name directly, the replacement works correctly. But I need something dynamic that does it for all methods in the subpackage.

I've tried creating both classes with all methods, but if I use `.method(ElementMatchers.any())` it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

I've tried using annotations with ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(AnnotationClass.class), but if I have two methods with the same annotation and different `value()` (for example `@AnnotationClass("hello")` and `@AnnotationClass("bye")`, it doesn't work. If only one method is annotated, it works.

I've also tried using the specific method name and it works, but I need something dynamic that does it for all methods in the subpackage.

I've tried using .method(ElementMatchers.any()) to see if it works for all methods, but it never replaces anything, even if there's only one method or multiple methods.

Comment: Have you tired what you are suggesting, but with an `AgentBuilder.Listener`? It seems to me that some of your attempts yield an error.